# Signal handlers not working across different process groups

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, posix

I am using `execp` under a child created using fork for which I have set new process group and have set it has foreground process group using `tcsetpgrp`

Here is my code for `main`

```
int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT,SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_IGN);
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid==-1)
    {
        perror("Error in forking");
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        setpgid(getpid(),getpid());
        //check denotes if process needs to be run in background or not
        if(!check)
        {
            tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO,getpgid(getpid()));
            tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO,getpgid(getpid()));
        }
        signal(SIGTSTP, tstphandler);
        signal(SIGINT,inthandler);
        if(strlen(token)>0)
        {
            execer=execlp(token,token,args,(char*)NULL);
            if (execer==-1)
            {
                printf("Error in execution);
            }
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //processes is a data structure which contains pid of    
        //processes and current status :- 0 = running in background                  
        //, 1= dead , 2 = stopped in background , -1= in foreground.
        if(check)
        {
            processes[pid_counter].pid=pid;
            processes[pid_counter].dead=0;
        }
        if(!check && strlen(token)>0)
        {
            processes[pid_counter].pid=pid;
            processes[pid_counter].dead=-1;
            waitpid(pid,&status,0);
            tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO,globalpgid);
            tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO,globalpgid);
            processes[pid_counter].dead=1;
        }
    }
}
```

and these are my handlers

```
//SIGINT handler
void inthandler(int sig)
{
    printf("int handler\n");
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=pid_counter;i++)
    {
        if(processes[i].dead==-1)
        {
            kill(processes[i].pid,SIGKILL);
            break;
        }
    }
}

//SIGTSTP handler
void tstphandler(int sig)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=pid_counter;i++)
    {
        if(processes[i].dead==-1)
        {
            processes[i].dead=2;
            kill(processes[i].pid, SIGSTOP);
            break;
        }
    }
    tcsetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO,globalpgid);
    tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO,globalpgid);
}
```

My problem is that these signal handlers are not being called from child processes. They are being called with their default action but not with my declared handler.

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question: Do you expect the signal-handlers to be inherited across the `execlp()`? If so, you are mistaken: `man execlp: [...]See the manual page for execve(2) for further details about the replacement of the current process image.[...]` Ok, then: `man execve: [...]The dispositions of any signals that are being caught are  reset  to the default (signal(7)).`.

Comment: Yes I want to inherit the handlers across excelp. If they can't be inherited what is the workaround for it?

Comment: There is no "workaround". The calling program image is replaced by the program that gets executed. The signal handlers are part of the program image (text-section, usually), so the old signal handlers are *gone*, just like the old functions, stack, address-space.

Comment: So nothing could be done to pass existing signal handlers or declare new handlers across exec?

Comment: You can write the corresponding signal-handler in the called program, *if* you have the source-code for it.

Comment: No I don't have its source code.

Comment: But won't the child would be having the declared signal handlers and since it's process group is in foreground it should respond to them.

Comment: Until it calls `exec*()`, the child *does* keep the signal-handlers. Afterwards, it does not. You can only cause the new process to start out *ignoring* a signal: `man execve: [...]POSIX.1-2001 specifies that the dispositions of any signals that are ignored  or  set  to  the  default are left unchanged.  POSIX.1-2001 specifies one exception: if SIGCHLD is being ignored, then an implementation  may  leave  the  disposition unchanged or reset it to the default; Linux does the former.[...]`.